# gazebo::common::Exception when running Gazebo as a library

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to run Gazebo as a library using the command

```
gazebo::setupClient(_argc, _argv);
```

and loading a world using

```
gazebo::physics::WorldPtr world = gazebo::loadWorld("worlds/empty.world");
```

I.e. I want to do what the example [custom_main](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/d6bfa5238c7c0cb3963716df16475b97f1f0051b/examples/stand_alone/custom_main/custom_main.cc?at=default) does.

However, when I compile and run this example (after running `gazebo` in a separate terminal), I get the following run-time error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'gazebo::common::Exception'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

`gazebo::setupClient(_argc, _argv);` returns true, but `gazebo::physics::WorldPtr world == NULL`. This is the case no matter the content of the string that I give to `gazebo::loadWorld()`. Looking at the source, I would expect to see some error messages in the console (or is that not where gzerr prints to?), but I don't, even if the string does not name a world file that exists.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7507/gazebo::common::exception-when-running-gazebo-as-a-library/) by [NickDP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/964/nickdp/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 186 on 2014-11-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You need to use `gazebo::setupServer`, not `gazebo::setupClient`. A `server` loads world, runs phyiscs, generates sensors data, etc. A `client` connects to a `server`. The gazebo GUI is an example of a `client`.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NickDP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/964/nickdp/) on 2014-11-20**:
I see. Now it works, thanks a lot. So if I want to write a main() that manipulates the robot models without using messages, the correct way of doing it is to call gazebo::setupServer() in my main() and then load my world/models thereafter. And then I do gzclient in a terminal?